# Unable to install homebrew in macos

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew

I am trying to install homebrew using command `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"` on my mac but I am getting this error:
`HEAD is now at aa937b902 Merge pull request #11474 from cho-m/fix-tar-validation`.

I'm using zsh and already installed the Xcode using the command `xcode-select --install`

What can I do to solve the error? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would try again later - that looks like Homebrew development have an issue with their git and is either a temporary glitch or they will fix it soon.

Comment: This is the pull request in question: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/11474 and HEAD is at that commit: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/commits/master -- I don't know if that's an error message, but an info message.

Comment: Have you ever installed Homebrew before? Can you try uninstalling first?

Comment: Which version of MacOS?

Comment: That's not an error message, whether you post it here on or Reddit.  Why are you "unable"?

Comment: Please add to the question the complete result of your installation attempt.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same "problem" recently. I let it hang for 5 minutes and it still just sat there. I then waited 10 minutes and no different. (I control-c'ed out after each wait.) I closed the terminal and re-opened it and tried again. It "hung" for only about 30 seconds and completed.